# Why doesn't this AutoHotkey script work?

Tags: autohotkey

I've written a script:

```
^!c::
ClipSave := ClipboardAll
Send ^x
Run calc.exe
WinWaitActive Calculator
Send %clipboard%
Send Enter
Sleep 100
Send ^c
;WinClose
Send ^v
Clipboard := ClipSave
```

it's supposed to auto-calculate highlighted text, but it keeps doing weird calculations. For instance, '2+3' comes out as something like "reciproc(ln(tan(cube(2))))". Wat am i missing?

Comment: A variation of this script could send the text to Google to calculate

Answer (score 2):

AutoHotkey sees the math symbols and turns them into AutoHotkey keystrokes. For example: + becomes Shift. So the calculator is taking 2 + 3 and interpreting it as the number 2 and Shift + 3.

Don't forget `Return` at the bottom of scripts, too. This might be triggering the extra junk as well.

I added some `Sleeps` as well, it was getting ahead of itself even with `ClipWait`.

Here is the script.

```
+^c::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
SendInput ^x
Run calc.exe
WinWaitActive Calculator
clipboard = %clipboard%
SendInput {Raw}%clipboard%
SendInput {Enter}
Sleep 100
SendInput ^c
Sleep 100
ClipWait, 2
WinClose
SendInput %clipboard%
Clipboard := ClipSaved
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

To send the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, you will want to enclose it in braces to specify it is a key.

Example:

```
Send {Enter}
```

Your call to `WinClose` is also commented out for some reason.

Comment: That helps, but now it just does cube(2)... Quite odd...

Comment: You may also want to try using `Send {Ctrl Down} {C Down} {Ctrl Up} {C Up}` instead of ^c. I've had issues with it in the past.

Comment: That didn't really help...